# Jenkins deploying war file to tomcat docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, docker

I'm trying deploy a WAR file to tomcat docker container.
Here config.xml :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.4.3">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git</url>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Maven>
      <targets>clean package</targets>
      <mavenName>3.3.9</mavenName>
      <usePrivateRepository>false</usePrivateRepository>
      <settings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider"/>
      <globalSettings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider"/>
    </hudson.tasks.Maven>
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher plugin="deploy@1.10">
      <adapters>
        <hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.Tomcat7xAdapter>
          <userName>admin</userName>
          <passwordScrambled>YWRtaW4=</passwordScrambled>
          <url>http://localhost:8888</url>
        </hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.Tomcat7xAdapter>
      </adapters>
      <contextPath>spring-petclinic</contextPath>
      <war>target/*.war</war>
      <onFailure>false</onFailure>
    </hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher>
  </publishers>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Results :

```
Tests run: 39, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ spring-petclinic ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy2Docker/workspace/target/spring-petclinic-1.4.2.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ spring-petclinic ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 51.388 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-25T15:52:20+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 87M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The job completed successfully, but docker container wasn't been created.
I checked that the war file is there.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 35689865 Dec 25 15:52 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy2Docker/workspace/target/spring-petclinic-1.4.2.jar
```

Anybody can help? What am I missing to make this works ?

Comment: Where's your command to run the image as a container? A build only creates to image, it doesn't run the container too.

Comment: You are right . thanks.